# ADF map source columns startswith to sink columns in SQL table

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a ADF data flow with many csv files as a source and a SQL database as a sink. The data in the csv files are similar with 170 plus columns wide however not all of the files have the same columns. Additionally, some column names are different in each file, but each column name starts with the same corresponding 3 digits. Example: 203-student name, 644-student GPA.

Is it possible to map source columns using the first 3 characters?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1. Go back to the data flow designer and edit the data flow.
2. Click on the parameters tab
3. Create a new parameter and choose string array data type
4. For the default value as per your requirement, enter ['203-student name','203-student grade',’203-student-marks']
5. Add a Select transformation. The Select transformation will be used to map incoming columns to new column names for output.
6. We're going to change the first 3 column names to the new names defined in the parameter
7. To do this, add 3 rule-based mapping entries in the bottom pane
8. For the first column, the matching rule will be position==1 and the name will be $parameter1[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrUXx.png)
9. Follow the same pattern for column 2 and 3
10. Click on the Inspect and Data Preview tabs of the Select transformation to view the new column name.

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-data-flow-dynamic-columns#parameterized-column-mapping